# Highcharts v4.0.4 plotting local timezone

Tags: highcharts, timezone

I am plotting UTC timestamps for an particular user whose timezone I know. Each data point is in the format `"2018-06-19 13:19:52.000Z"` and was added to the series of points to be plotted as `moment("2018-06-19 13:19:52.000Z").tz(this.tiemZone).valueOf()`.

When the point is plotted, it is plotted as `6/19 13:19:52`, but I would like this to be plotted in the user's timezone, so something like `6/19 6:19:52`.

I read that Highcharts plots in UTC, but that if I set `useUTC: false` (somewhere), that it would plot in the current browser's timezone, but I actually want to plot in the user's timezone, e.g. if the timezone is "Los Angeles", then the above time would be `6:19:52`.

```
time = new window.Highcharts.setOptions({
     time: {
         timezone: _that.timeZone,
         timezoneOffset: _that.offset
     }
}, this);

return  '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%d %H:%M:%S',
                        this.x)
                    + ' - ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + ' ' + toolTipUnits;
```

The offset I calculated after taking the moment of one of the UTC timestamps:

`moment(data[0][0]).tz(this.timeZone)._offset`, here is was equal to `-420`

I tried something the above, but the tooltip still shows the UTC time `13:19:52`. Any advice?

************************ UPDATE*****************************

```
time = new Highcharts.setOptions({
   global: {
      timezone: _that.timeZone,
      timezoneOffset: _that.offset
   }
}, this);

return  '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%d %H:%M:%S', this.x)
                    + ' - ' + window.Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + ' ' + toolTipUnits;
```

I updated the code as shown above, and now the data point is being plotted as `6/19 20:19:52`, even though I am adding `-420` to the data point (`this.x`). Looking into this, but any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're simply going in the opposite direction.

From the Highcharts API documentation, it says "positive values are west, negative values are east of UTC." If you assume `6/19 13:19:52` is UTC time, and you want `6/19 6:19:52` (seven hours **west** of UTC), then you'll want to set a positive number for your offset (`timezoneOffset: 420`). What you're doing now is setting a negative number (`-420`), so it's returning an offset for seven hours **east** of UTC.

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time.timezoneOffset

I hope this is helpful for you.

(Also, can I assume that in your return code, you're using this in the tooltip formatter?)

Comment: Correct, I am using the tooltip and that works, it was just the offset that looked wrong. I actually had just noticed the missing negative and added it, and I think it seems to work for data points I have visually tested.